# Side bar has undefined height and misplaced image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure I'm overcomplicating this in my head, but is the following layout possible using the standard bootstrap 3 grid system?

Header and sub header can fill 12 columns. Then Image, probably fixed height, spans 8-col then a side bar which spans 4-col. The problem is the side bar has an undefined height and the underneath of the image is content.

So far got something like:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
    image
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
   Navigation down right
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
    Content
 </div>
</div>
```

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnbsJ.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image

[image: OP's image]

You should use the following layout (Click the "Full page" button to see it in action.  Also, ignore the CSS.  It's just for testing purposes):

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

[class*='col-'] > div:not(.row) {
  background: #DDD;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5em;
}
.red [class*='col-'] > div:not(.row) {
  background: #C55;
  color: #FFF;
  height: auto;
}

[class*='col-sm-4'] > div:not(.row) {
  height: 9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div>HEADER</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div>SUB HEADER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div>IMAGE</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div>LEFT COL</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div>RIGHT COL</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially you want a nested row with 6 wide columns for a 12 column grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap row has **only twelve spans**. I see that 8 + 4 + 8 = 20 > 12, so the "content" div will be at a new line...

And you can't put `col-sm-x` with `col-md-x` in the same row...

My suggestion: split into two rows

```
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           image
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
            Navigation down right
       </div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
           Content
       </div>
   </div>
```

But If you want all of it in the same row:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-5">
           image
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
            Navigation down right
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-5">
           Content
       </div>
   </div>
```

And if you want a side section, you can cascade rows:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12">
       <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   Image
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   Content
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
            Navigation down right
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, yes apologies my html was wrong, i copied it from where i kept trying different solutions and didnt resort it out well enough. Thats got me where i needed to be. Think i just had some sort of brain fade.